# Find date of last update for specific value in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that represents the entirety of a row's update history from another table.
Ex:

| HistoryId | PrimaryId | ValA | ValB | ValC | ValD | ValE | UpdatedBy | UpdatedOn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 56 | 100 | 20 | 50 | 50 | NULL | david | 1/4/2024 |
| 3 | 56 | 100 | 30 | 50 | 50 | NULL | cameron | 1/3/2024 |
| 2 | 56 | 50 | 30 | 50 | 50 | NULL | bob | 1/2/2024 |
| 1 | 56 | 50 | 40 | 25 | 50 | NULL | alice | 1/1/2024 |

In this case, the last person to update ValD was alice on 1/1, since the value hasn't changed since she entered it. ValA was changed on 1/3 by cameron, Val B was changed on 1/4 by david, and ValC was changed on 1/3 by bob. ValE has never had a value other than NULL, and thus has never been updated.

How do I get a list of who the last person was to update each value in the row, and when? I've been trying a CTE like:

```
WITH _valA AS 
(
    SELECT 
        PrimaryId, ValA, UpdatedBy, UpdatedOn, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PrimaryId, UpdatedOn) AS RowNo
    FROM 
        table
    WHERE 
        PrimaryId = @PrimaryId
        AND HistoryId >= (SELECT TOP 1 HistoryId FROM table 
                          WHERE PrimaryId = @PrimaryId 
                            AND ValA != NULL 
                          ORDER BY HistoryId)
), 
_aMax AS 
(
    SELECT 
        s.PrimaryId, MAX(s.UpdatedOn) AS UpdatedOn
    FROM 
        _valA s
    LEFT JOIN 
        _valA p ON p.PrimaryId = s.PrimaryId
                AND p.RowNo + 1 = s.RowNo
    WHERE 
        p._valA != s._valA
    GROUP BY 
        s.PrimaryId
),
_valB AS 
(
    SELECT 
        PrimaryId, ValB, UpdatedBy, UpdatedOn, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PrimaryId, UpdatedOn) AS RowNo
    FROM 
        table
    WHERE 
        PrimaryId = @PrimaryId
        AND HistoryId >= (SELECT TOP 1 HistoryId FROM table 
                          WHERE PrimaryId = @PrimaryId 
                            AND ValB != NULL
                          ORDER BY HistoryId)
),
_bMax AS 
(
    SELECT 
        s.PrimaryId, MAX(s.UpdatedOn) AS UpdatedOn
    FROM 
        _valB s
    LEFT JOIN 
        _valB p ON p.PrimaryId = s.PrimaryId
                AND p.RowNo + 1 = s.RowNo
    WHERE 
        p._valB != s._valB
    GROUP BY 
        s.PrimaryId
),

SELECT 
    a.UpdatedOn AS ValAUpdatedOn,
    a.UpdatedBy AS ValAUpdatedBy,
    b.UpdatedOn AS ValBUpdatedOn,
    b.UpdatedBy AS ValBUpdatedBy
FROM 
    _valA a
JOIN 
    _aMax am ON am.PrimaryId = a.PrimaryId
             AND am.UpdatedOn = a.UpdatedOn
JOIN 
    _valB b ON b.PrimaryId = a.PrimaryId
JOIN 
    _bMax bm ON bm.PrimaryId = b.PrimaryId
             AND bm.UpdatedOn = b.UpdatedOn
```

Where `PrimaryId` links to the primary key of the other table, so we can see the history of row 56 here. That historyid >= check is designed to remove all initial instances of null in a value's history. A value is considered entered once the first non-null value exists. If the value is later set back to null, that is considered a material change and we do care about that.

Problems I'm having include, that if the value was always null, the _valA CTE will have 0 rows, in which case I want to return null for the date and user update. The way I'm returning these values makes this impossible.

Also, when I am returning multiple vals, that join from _valB to _valA is bad in a way I'm having trouble describing, but I know it's wrong.

In my real solution I am trying to return all values A through E, I just stopped it at B for brevity's sake.

I could be completely off track on my solution, but I'm been looking at this for a while and I'm starting to lose the plot. Is there perhaps a different (simpler) approach I could be taking?

Comment: Is this a temporal table - and if not, why not? Please also provide your expected results for the sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your specific data the following I believe meets the criteria you have described - note that an actual example of your desired results would clarify and depending on how accurately your sample data represents your real data, tweaks may be required. Note in your description I think ValC date is incorrect it look like 02 not 03.

```
with seq as (
    select * , Row_Number() over(partition by primaryId order by HistoryId desc) rn
    from t
)
select v1.*, v2.*, v3.*, v4.*, v5.* 
from seq s
outer apply (
    select top(1) UpdatedBy A_UpdatedBy, UpdatedOn A_UpdatedOn from t 
    where t.PrimaryId = s.PrimaryId and t.ValA = s.ValA 
    order by t.HistoryId 
)v1
outer apply (
    select top(1) UpdatedBy B_UpdatedBy, UpdatedOn B_UpdatedOn from t 
    where t.PrimaryId = s.PrimaryId and t.ValB = s.ValB
    order by t.HistoryId 
)v2
outer apply (
    select top(1) UpdatedBy C_UpdatedBy, UpdatedOn C_UpdatedOn from t 
    where t.PrimaryId = s.PrimaryId and t.ValC = s.ValC
    order by t.HistoryId 
)v3
outer apply (
    select top(1) UpdatedBy D_UpdatedBy, UpdatedOn D_UpdatedOn from t 
    where t.PrimaryId = s.PrimaryId and t.ValD = s.ValD
    order by t.HistoryId 
)v4
outer apply (
    select top(1) UpdatedBy E_UpdatedBy, UpdatedOn E_updatedOn from t 
    where t.PrimaryId = s.PrimaryId and t.ValE = s.ValE
    order by t.HistoryId 
)v5
where rn = 1;
```

See a [working demo Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/b9UajQbC)

Comment: I _think_ it might fail if the sequence of changes is, e.g., 1, 2, 2, 1. Note that the latest value is 1 but it was set to 1 earlier by someone other than the last person.

Comment: Possibly although I think it could be made to work, needs a more comprehensive set of data to test against, hence the caveat comments above; it's something the OP can at least try and tweak or disgard if unsuitable.

Comment: This is closest to the solution I went with. I do agree that if the sequence of changes is 1,2,2,1, the data will not be accurate. However, in my specific use case, it is actually unlikely that once a number is changed, that change will be reverted. Because of this specific property of the application, I'm going with this change.

Comment: Replacing `t.ValX = s.ValX` with  `t.ValX IS NOT DISTINCT FROM s.ValX` (for each of the 5 comparisons) will better handle null cases.  Still getting one unexpected value when I ran against some extra test data [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/sV3TCMMj). For PrimaryId = 91 I'm getting C_UpdatedBy = "Larry" when I expected "Shep".

Comment: @TN Yes I agree, not at PC presently now away however I tried I think exactly that first using offset fetch unfortunately you can't offset by a negative value, boo.

Comment: I pulled my comment because I realized that there might not be a prior mismatch, so things were getting  more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation of gaps and islands. A potential solution is:

```sql
SELECT  -- 4) Aggs
    MAX(CASE WHEN rowA = 1 AND valA IS NOT NULL THEN updatedby END) AS updatedA
,   MAX(CASE WHEN rowB = 1 AND valB IS NOT NULL THEN updatedby END) AS updatedB
,   MAX(CASE WHEN rowC = 1 AND valC IS NOT NULL THEN updatedby END) AS updatedC
,   MAX(CASE WHEN rowD = 1 AND valD IS NOT NULL THEN updatedby END) AS updatedD
,   MAX(CASE WHEN rowE = 1 AND valE IS NOT NULL THEN updatedby END) AS updatedE
,   MAX(CASE WHEN rowA = 1 AND valA IS NOT NULL THEN realDate END) AS updatedOnA
,   MAX(CASE WHEN rowB = 1 AND valB IS NOT NULL THEN realDate END) AS updatedOnB
,   MAX(CASE WHEN rowC = 1 AND valC IS NOT NULL THEN realDate END) AS updatedOnC
,   MAX(CASE WHEN rowD = 1 AND valD IS NOT NULL THEN realDate END) AS updatedOnD
,   MAX(CASE WHEN rowE = 1 AND valE IS NOT NULL THEN realDate END) AS updatedOnE
,   MAX(CASE WHEN rowA = 1 THEN valA END) AS ValA
,   MAX(CASE WHEN rowB = 1 THEN valB END) AS ValB
,   MAX(CASE WHEN rowC = 1 THEN valC END) AS ValC
,   MAX(CASE WHEN rowD = 1 THEN valD END) AS ValD
,   MAX(CASE WHEN rowE = 1 THEN valE END) AS ValE
FROM    (
    SELECT  -- 3) Rows
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY grpA DESC, realDate) AS rowA
    ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY grpB DESC, realDate) AS rowB
    ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY grpC DESC, realDate) AS rowC
    ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY grpD DESC, realDate) AS rowD
    ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY grpE DESC, realDate) AS rowE
    ,   *
    FROM    (
        SELECT  *
            -- 2) Sum
        ,   SUM(flagA) OVER(ORDER BY realDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS grpA
        ,   SUM(flagB) OVER(ORDER BY realDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS grpB
        ,   SUM(flagC) OVER(ORDER BY realDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS grpC
        ,   SUM(flagD) OVER(ORDER BY realDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS grpD
        ,   SUM(flagE) OVER(ORDER BY realDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS grpE
        FROM    (
            SELECT  *
            -- 1) Flag
            ,   CASE WHEN lag(vala) OVER(ORDER BY realdate) = vala OR vala IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS flagA
            ,   CASE WHEN lag(valb) OVER(ORDER BY realdate) = valb OR valb IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS flagB
            ,   CASE WHEN lag(valc) OVER(ORDER BY realdate) = valc OR valc IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS flagC
            ,   CASE WHEN lag(vald) OVER(ORDER BY realdate) = vald OR vald IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS flagD
            ,   CASE WHEN lag(vale) OVER(ORDER BY realdate) = vale OR vale IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS flagE
            FROM    (
                SELECT  *
                ,   cast(updatedon AS datetime) AS realDate
                FROM    (
                    VALUES  (4, 56, 100, 20, 50, 50, CAST(NULL AS INT), N'david', N'1/4/2024')
                    ,   (3, 56, 100, 30, 50, 50, CAST(NULL AS INT), N'cameron', N'1/3/2024')
                    ,   (2, 56, 50, 30, 50, 50, CAST(NULL AS INT), N'bob', N'1/2/2024')
                    ,   (1, 56, 50, 40, 25, 50, CAST(NULL AS INT), N'alice', N'1/1/2024')
                ) t (HistoryId,primaryid,vala,valb,valc,vald,vale,updatedby,updatedon)
                ) x
            ) x
        ) x
    ) x
```

There is mostly a lot of copypasting between the columns, but the actual parts are quite few, and as usual, the gaps and islands SQL starts from the bottom to the top (i've added the comments with numbers to the code):

1. Generate a flag that compares previous value to current. If yes, we set the group flag to 0, otherwise to 1
2. Summarize the flags to create "islands" of same values
3. Find the first row of the last group
4. Finally, for each column, aggregate and find the value we need. `CASE WHEN rowA = 1 THEN valA END` is a conditional aggregation trick that returns the value from first row

The result is list of values:

| updatedA | updatedB | updatedC | updatedD | updatedE | updatedOnA | updatedOnB | updatedOnC | updatedOnD | updatedOnE | ValA | ValB | ValC | ValD | ValE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cameron | david | bob | alice | NULL | 2024-01-03 | 2024-01-04 | 2024-01-02 | 2024-01-01 | NULL | 100 | 20 | 50 | 50 | NULL |

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to locate all the latest values by using the greatest `historyId` (assume this is a incremental Id by the date entered). And use the associated values to trace back to the table to get who got that value first.

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
   SELECT ValA,ValB, ValC, ValD, ValE
   FROM YOUR_TABLE
   WHERE HistoryId = (SELECT MAX(HistoryId) FROM YOUR_TABLE)
),
CTE_ValA
AS
(
    SELECT A.UpdatedBy, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY A.ValA ORDER BY A.HistoryId ASC) as RN
    FROM YOUR_TABLE as A
    INNER JOIN CTE as B
    ON B.ValA = A.ValA
),
CTE_ValB
AS
(
    SELECT A.UpdatedBy, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY A.ValB ORDER BY A.HistoryId ASC) as RN
    FROM YOUR_TABLE as A
    INNER JOIN CTE as B
    ON B.ValB = A.ValB
),
CTE_ValC
AS
(
    SELECT A.UpdatedBy, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY A.ValC ORDER BY A.HistoryId ASC) as RN
    FROM YOUR_TABLE as A
    INNER JOIN CTE as B
    ON B.ValC = A.ValC
),
CTE_ValD
AS
(
    SELECT A.UpdatedBy, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY A.ValD ORDER BY A.HistoryId ASC) as RN
    FROM YOUR_TABLE as A
    INNER JOIN CTE as B
    ON B.ValD = A.ValD
)
SELECT A.*, 
       B.UpdatedBy as ValA_LastUpdatedBy, 
       C.UpdatedBy as ValB_LastUpdatedBy, 
       D.UpdatedBy as ValC_LastUpdatedBy, 
       E.UpdatedBy as ValD_LastUpdatedBy
FROM CTE as A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM CTE_ValA WHERE RN = 1) as B ON  1=1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM CTE_ValB WHERE RN = 1) as C ON  1=1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM CTE_ValC WHERE RN = 1) as D ON  1=1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM CTE_ValD WHERE RN = 1) as E ON  1=1
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you need. This will scan the history and use `LAG()` to examine and identify the prior value. These intermediate results are then unpivoted using a `CROSS APPLY` to allow the latest change selection to be done in one batch. The results are then joined back up with the History table and unpivoted using *conditional aggregation*.

I have included two different views of the results (vertical/unpivoted and horizontal/pivoted). You can run with what works best for you.

This approach should be easily scaled up and may be suitable for use in a dynamic SQL environment where the tracked columns change from table to table.

```
;WITH CTE_LatestChanges AS (
    SELECT 
        HL.PrimaryId,
        A.ColumnName,
        MAX(HL.HistoryId) AS HistoryId
    FROM (
        SELECT
             H.*,
             LAG(H.ValA) OVER(PARTITION BY PrimaryId ORDER BY HistoryId) AS LagValA,
             LAG(H.ValB) OVER(PARTITION BY PrimaryId ORDER BY HistoryId) AS LagValB,
             LAG(H.ValC) OVER(PARTITION BY PrimaryId ORDER BY HistoryId) AS LagValC,
             LAG(H.ValD) OVER(PARTITION BY PrimaryId ORDER BY HistoryId) AS LagValD,
             LAG(H.ValE) OVER(PARTITION BY PrimaryId ORDER BY HistoryId) AS LagValE,
             LAG(H.HistoryId) OVER(PARTITION BY PrimaryId ORDER BY HistoryId) AS LagHistoryId
        FROM History H
    ) HL
    CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES -- If not all of the same type, a cast to (N)VARCHAR(MAX) may be needed
            ('ValA', HL.ValA, HL.LagValA),
            ('ValB', HL.ValB, HL.LagValB),
            ('ValC', HL.ValC, HL.LagValC),
            ('ValD', HL.ValD, HL.LagValD),
            ('ValE', HL.ValE, HL.LagValE)
    ) A(ColumnName, UpdatedValue, PriorValue)
    WHERE A.UpdatedValue IS DISTINCT FROM A.PriorValue
    OR HL.LagHistoryId IS NULL  -- Omit this if you do not want to count initial nulls
    GROUP BY HL.PrimaryId, A.ColumnName
),
CTE_Details1 AS (
    SELECT C.PrimaryId, C.ColumnName, H.UpdatedBy, H.UpdatedOn
    FROM CTE_LatestChanges C
    JOIN History H
        ON H.HistoryId = C.HistoryId
),
CTE_Details2 AS (
    SELECT
        C.PrimaryId,
        MAX(CASE WHEN C.ColumnName = 'ValA' THEN H.UpdatedBy END) AS ValAUpdatedBy,
        MAX(CASE WHEN C.ColumnName = 'ValA' THEN H.UpdatedOn END) AS ValAUpdatedOn,
        MAX(CASE WHEN C.ColumnName = 'ValB' THEN H.UpdatedBy END) AS ValBUpdatedBy,
        MAX(CASE WHEN C.ColumnName = 'ValB' THEN H.UpdatedOn END) AS ValBUpdatedOn,
        MAX(CASE WHEN C.ColumnName = 'ValC' THEN H.UpdatedBy END) AS ValCUpdatedBy,
        MAX(CASE WHEN C.ColumnName = 'ValC' THEN H.UpdatedOn END) AS ValCUpdatedOn,
        MAX(CASE WHEN C.ColumnName = 'ValD' THEN H.UpdatedBy END) AS ValDUpdatedBy,
        MAX(CASE WHEN C.ColumnName = 'ValD' THEN H.UpdatedOn END) AS ValDUpdatedOn,
        MAX(CASE WHEN C.ColumnName = 'ValE' THEN H.UpdatedBy END) AS ValEUpdatedBy,
        MAX(CASE WHEN C.ColumnName = 'ValE' THEN H.UpdatedOn END) AS ValEUpdatedOn
    FROM CTE_LatestChanges C
    JOIN History H
        ON H.HistoryId = C.HistoryId
    GROUP BY C.PrimaryId
)
--SELECT * FROM CTE_Details1 ORDER BY PrimaryId  -- Vertical view
SELECT * FROM CTE_Details2 ORDER BY PrimaryId    -- Flat view
```

The above uses the new `IS DISTINCT FROM` comparison operator to cleanly handle null to/from non-null value transitions. If you are using an older SQL Server version that does not support this, you can use a alternative comparison:

```
    WHERE A.UpdatedValue <> A.PriorValue
    OR IIF(A.UpdatedValue IS NULL, 1, 0) <> IIF(A.PriorValue IS NULL, 1, 0)
```

If you wish to exclude/ignore initial null value inserts, you can comment-out or remove the `OR HL.LagHistoryId IS NULL` condition.

If your column types are not all the same, you will need to modify the `CROSS APPLY(VALUES ...))` list to apply a `CAST(... AS NVARCHAR(MAX))` on each value.

Results:

| PrimaryId | ValAUpdatedBy | ValAUpdatedOn | ValBUpdatedBy | ValBUpdatedOn | ValCUpdatedBy | ValCUpdatedOn | ValDUpdatedBy | ValDUpdatedOn | ValEUpdatedBy | ValEUpdatedOn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 56 | cameron | 2024-01-03 | david | 2024-01-04 | bob | 2024-01-02 | alice | 2024-01-01 | alice | 2024-01-01 |

Alternate vertical/unpivoted Results:

| PrimaryId | ColumnName | UpdatedBy | UpdatedOn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 56 | ValA | cameron | 2024-01-03 |
| 56 | ValB | david | 2024-01-04 |
| 56 | ValC | bob | 2024-01-02 |
| 56 | ValD | alice | 2024-01-01 |
| 56 | ValE | alice | 2024-01-01 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VrZK3UPn) for a demo that includes additional cases showing correct handling of changes to/from NULL.

Answer (score 0):

I think this gets you what you want and covers the requirement to report a null when the value has never changed. There might be some recent SQL Server features available that would help clean this up bit. There's a second, shorter, and more efficient example within the fiddle that uses SQL Server's `first_value(C) ignore nulls` option and basically gets rid of the middle step. I didn't want to make that assumption here yet.

This one uses `lead()` to detect changes and then pivots all data into a single result. (Comparing nulls is often done by converting them to an impossible value.) After the pivot you can easily pick out the first value without having to deal with nulls from other rows in the mix:

```
with data as (
    select *,
        -- these are assumed to be not null columns
        case when ValA <> lead(ValA, 1, ValA) over (partition by PrimaryId order by HistoryId desc)
             then 'A' end ChangeA,
        case when ValB <> lead(ValB, 1, ValB) over (partition by PrimaryId order by HistoryId desc)
             then 'B' end ChangeB,
        case when ValC <> lead(ValC, 1, ValC) over (partition by PrimaryId order by HistoryId desc)
             then 'C' end ChangeC,
        case when ValD <> lead(ValD, 1, ValD) over (partition by PrimaryId order by HistoryId desc)
             then 'D' end ChangeD,
        -- next column is nullable  
        case when coalesce(ValE, -99999999) <> coalesce(lead(ValE, 1, ValE) over (partition by PrimaryId order by HistoryId desc), -99999999)
             then 'E' end as ChangeE
    from History
), pvt as (
    select *
    from
        (select distinct PrimaryId from History) as i cross apply
        (values ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D'), ('E')) as r(col) outer apply
        (select HistoryId, UpdatedBy, UpdatedOn from data
         where i.PrimaryId = PrimaryId and r.col in (ChangeA, ChangeB, ChangeC, ChangeD, ChangeE)
        ) as u
)
select distinct PrimaryId,
    first_value(UpdatedBy) over (partition by PrimaryId order by case when col = 'A' then 0 else 1 end, HistoryId desc) as UpdatedByA,
    first_value(UpdatedOn) over (partition by PrimaryId order by case when col = 'A' then 0 else 1 end, HistoryId desc) as UpdatedOnA,
    first_value(UpdatedBy) over (partition by PrimaryId order by case when col = 'B' then 0 else 1 end, HistoryId desc) as UpdatedByB,
    first_value(UpdatedOn) over (partition by PrimaryId order by case when col = 'B' then 0 else 1 end, HistoryId desc) as UpdatedOnB,
    first_value(UpdatedBy) over (partition by PrimaryId order by case when col = 'C' then 0 else 1 end, HistoryId desc) as UpdatedByC,
    first_value(UpdatedOn) over (partition by PrimaryId order by case when col = 'C' then 0 else 1 end, HistoryId desc) as UpdatedOnC,
    first_value(UpdatedBy) over (partition by PrimaryId order by case when col = 'D' then 0 else 1 end, HistoryId desc) as UpdatedByD,
    first_value(UpdatedOn) over (partition by PrimaryId order by case when col = 'D' then 0 else 1 end, HistoryId desc) as UpdatedOnD,
    first_value(UpdatedBy) over (partition by PrimaryId order by case when col = 'E' then 0 else 1 end, HistoryId desc) as UpdatedByE,
    first_value(UpdatedOn) over (partition by PrimaryId order by case when col = 'E' then 0 else 1 end, HistoryId desc) as UpdatedOnE
from pvt;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/m2y65UG0?hide=4